# When is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ defined and continuous

Tags: calculus, power-series

So $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$. For which values of $x$ is $f$ defined? What about continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your series convergent for $f(x)$ to be defined. And your series is only convergent when $x>0$.
You can also actually evaluate the series:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-nx} \\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{-nx} \\
&= -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx} \\
&= -\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}\right) \\
&=\frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1-e^{-x}\right)^2} \\
&=\frac{e^x}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}
\end{align}
Your series is then continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this stuff and was getting mixed up with all these definitions.

Comment: You're welcome!