# On which intervals is convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-nx}$ uniform?

Tags: real-analysis

I know from [When is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ defined and continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743593/when-is-fx-sum-n-1-inftyne-nx-defined-and-continuous) that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-nx}=\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$ for $x>0$.

On which intervals is the convergence uniform?

My hunch is that we would encounter problems near $0$ and so the interval would be $(a,\ \infty)$ where $a$ is any positive real number. I'm guessing there ought to be a convenient theorem we could use rather than derive this from first principles.

Comment: Weierstrass M-test? The intervals are of the form $[a, \infty) $. I think it is also easy to use first principles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x\in [a,\infty)$ then $|ne^{-nx}|\leq |ne^{-na}|$. Weierstrass $M$-test says that if for every $x\in E$ we have that $|f_n(x)|\leq |g_n|$ and $\sum |g_n|<\infty$ then $\sum f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.